# Looping through rows in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I am trying to figure out how to loop through the 'pandas' dataframe in Python.

Here is the CSV file which I am trying to read:
[csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSnVO.png)

Here is the Python codes which I have so far; please help me identifying what I am missing:

---

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_csv("E://Test1.csv")

data_org = data[data['Distance']>1]

Distance = data_org.iloc[:,0]
Temperature=data_org.iloc[:,1:]

#Label for legend with timestamp  ---> wont print date
Date = data_org.iloc[:,1]
print (Date)

for i in Temperature:
    print (i)
    Temperature[i]= Temperature[:,i:]   --> wont iterate

 for p in Temperature:
    plt.plot(x,y, 'b')

    plt.xlabel('Distance [m]')
    plt.ylabel('Temperature [oC]')
    plt.legend(loc='lower right')

    #Changing Name for each Iteration
    plt.savefig('E://%s.png' % Date [i])
```

Comment: You're looking for [`df.iterrows()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html).

Comment: Thank you I will check it out~

Comment: I would make 'Distance' the `index` of the DataFrame and transpose the DataFrame. Then you have neat columns with the temperatures with the particular distances as columnsand the timestamp the index. It should be easy to iterate over it (`iteritems()`) and plot

Comment: PS, a csv is something you can easily copy-paste into SO, so we can actually use the data instead of a printscreen